# Dense subspace of the space of measures on the torus $\mathbb{T}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Every measure $\mu$ on the torus $\mathbb{T}$ is the weak-$\ast$ limit of a sequence of absolutely continuous measures on $\mathbb{T}$ with $C^{\infty}$ densities. I'd like to see a proof of this fact. I've read that the Stone–Weierstrass theorem may be involved.

Could someone point me to a reference for the proof or help me to correct/make rigourous the following one?

"Proof:"

1. Let $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$ and $f_{\epsilon}(x) = \epsilon^{-1}f(\epsilon^{-1}x)$.
2. $\mu \ast f_{\epsilon} \rightarrow \mu$ in weak-$\ast$ [?]
3. $\mu \ast f_{\epsilon}$ is continuous [?]
4. By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, $\forall \eta > 0$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists g_{\eta,\epsilon} \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$ such that
   $$
   \|\mu \ast f_{\epsilon} - g_{\eta,\epsilon} \|_{\infty} < \eta.
   $$
5. $g_{\eta,\epsilon} \rightarrow \mu$ in weak-$\ast$ [?]

Comment: I guess that it is even simpler than that. Take a mollifying family $\eta_{\epsilon}$ and take the convolution against the measure $\mu$. The result is a smooth function that approximates $\mu$ the better the smaller $\epsilon$. (That should work but I have not filled in the details)

Comment: I think you are right that in 3. continuity can be upgraded to $C^{\infty}$. 2. is not clear to me.

Comment: I wrote an answer, please see if it is useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**. Take a mollifying family $\eta_\epsilon$. The convolution $\eta_\epsilon \ast \mu$ is a smooth function.

To prove that $\eta_\epsilon \ast \mu$ converges to $\mu$ in the weak-$\ast$ sense, use Fubini's theorem to derive the following expression for pairing of $\eta_\epsilon\ast \mu$ against an arbitrary function $\phi\in C(\mathbb{T})$: 
$$
\langle \eta_\epsilon \ast \mu, \phi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{T}}(\eta^\surd_\epsilon \ast \phi)(y)\, \mu(dy),$$
where $\eta_\epsilon^\surd(y)=\eta_\epsilon(-y)$.

Now you have a convolution of the *function* $\phi$ against a mollifying family. You can then access all the usual results you already know.

Comment: I find that finiteness of the measure is used in two places: Once for Fubini and once for passing from uniform convergence of $\eta_{\epsilon}^{\surd} \ast \phi \rightarrow \phi$ to convergence of $\int_{\mathbb{T}} (\eta_{\epsilon}^{\surd} \ast \phi) d\mu$ $\rightarrow$ $\int_{\mathbb{T}} \phi d\mu$

Comment: @JasonJones: Yes. But the torus is compact, so every Radon measure is automatically finite.